# Django 3 UUID router returns 404

Tags: django

I have a simple model:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Localhost (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views

```
def localhost(request, localhost_id):
    localhost = get_object_or_404(Localhost, id=localhost_id)
    return render(request, 'local.html', {'localhost':localhost})
```

and urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name='home'),
        path( 'f/<uuid:localhost_id>/', views.localhost, name='localhost'),
           ]
```

I have a record in the DB as tested here

```
SELECT * FROM `app_localhost` WHERE `id` = '5d7d555861f2487d8ea147e8b274e267'
```

but loading the route with /f/5d7d555861f2487d8ea147e8b274e267

returns not found

```
Not Found: /f/5d7d555861f2487d8ea147e8b274e267
[10/Feb/2020 10:06:10] "GET /f/5d7d555861f2487d8ea147e8b274e267 HTTP/1.1" 404 2682
```

There is probably something I am doing wrong but I can't figure out what. I did check the manual and everything seems to be according to the specifications.

Comment: did you solve it? which version of Django  are you using?

Comment: @ShubhamDevgan not solved, django 3.0.2

Comment: That would be because `5d7d555861f2487d8ea147e8b274e267` is not a valid UUID... it must be in the standard form, e.g., `16fd2706-8baf-433b-82eb-8c7fada847da`.

Comment: @solarissmoke thank you for this but how do I get a standard format? this was generated automatically from the model... and is stored in the db like that

Comment: I don't think it can be stored like that. How are you extracting the value from the database to generate your URL?

Comment: @solarissmoke it can. It seems to be a bug in the Django model UUID when working with mysql. It works with     id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, default=fo_id, editable=False) this stores it with the correct -  if I use the models.UUIDField the - are not saved in MySQL